# Ajax breaking .on('click', eventhandler)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table of items that has a column of links that can be clicked to open a floating menu. I also have a sidebar link that will perform an ajax request and will sort the results (it repopulates the table with a new table). When the table results haven't been sorted (repopulated by the ajax call), the links work fine. However, when I sort results and the ajax request is performed, the links in the table no longer work.

I was wondering how I can preserve the click events within the table links? I thought jQuery's .on(selector, eventhandler) takes care of this, but it seems to not be the case in my situation.

[image]

This is what I currently have for the table links' click events:

```
  $('.addSet').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return menuShow(this);
  });

  $('.addSetMenu input, .addSetMenu select, .addSetMenu').on('click', function(event) {
    return event.stopPropagation();
  });

  menuShow = function(menuParent) {
    var menu, parentLeft, parentOffset, parentTop;
    menu = $(menuParent).siblings('.addSetMenu');
    parentOffset = $(menuParent).offset();
    parentTop = parentOffset.top;
    parentLeft = parentOffset.left;
    $(menu).css({
      'top': parentTop + 20,
      'left': parentLeft - 160
    });
    resetMenu();
    return $(menu).toggleClass('hide');
  };

  $('html, .setCancelBtn').on('click', function() {
    return resetMenu();
  });

  resetMenu = function() {
    var menu;
    menu = $('.addSetMenu input[type=text]');
    $('.addSetMenu select').val('default');
    $(menu).addClass('hide');
    $(menu).val('');
    return $('.addSetMenu').addClass('hide');
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your table gets repopulated, corresponding DOM nodes of those links get removed. So do all their event handlers. You should hook onto some parent element, for example your table. And from there you can catch propagated events.

```
$('table-selector').on('click', 'urlSelector', function(event) {
    //handler code
})
```

See "Direct and delegated events" here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried out a parent that's further up the DOM that doesn't get replaced, but then my trouble is dealing with the link object being passed into menuShow(menuParent) not being properly passed in. $('.addSet').on() maintains the clicked link I'm passing into that function, but then all the nodes get removed after the ajax call.

Comment: @SCS, event handler receives `event` argument. You can use `event.target` in your event handler to get `.addStaff`-element reference.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('.addSet').on('click', function(event) {
  //some code
});
```

to

```
$(document).on("click",".addSet", function(event) {
  //some code
});
```